# Display `dplyr` groups ordered by their corresponding value (not name) in `geom_point`

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Using the `mpg` dataset I want to produce a scatterplot that shows for every `manufacturer` one point with the grouped (by `manufacturer`) mean of `displ`.

The following works so far:

```
ggplot(mpg %>% 
         group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
         summarise(mean_displ = mean(displ))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = manufacturer, y = mean_displ)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Now I want to show the points in ascending order according to their `displ` value. Or: I want to sort the `manufacturer` variable on the x-axis according to the corresponding `mean_displ` value.

I tried to insert a `arrange(mean_displ)` statement in my `dplyr` chain. No success.

So I introduced a dummy variable `x` that produces the plot I want, but now the labeling is gone..

```
ggplot(mpg %>% 
         group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
         summarise(mean_displ = mean(displ)) %>%
         arrange(mean_displ) %>%
         mutate(x = 1:15)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = mean_displ))
```

[image]

How can I get the later plot but with the labeling from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fct_reorder` from the `forcats` package can order the levels of a factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(mpg %>% 
         group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
         summarise(mean_displ = mean(displ))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = fct_reorder(manufacturer, mean_displ), y = mean_displ)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 90))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's it. I definitely need to look into `forcats`.